# ADODB - password encryption

Tags: php, encryption, adodb

I have a `.asp` file that is making LDAP queries on the `"AUTH_USER"`.  The Domain Controllers are refusing unencrypted passwords.

I cannot find any documentation on how ADODB is actually encrypting the password when the following property is set.

```
oConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
```

I need to replicate this in PHP but cannot find any documentation on how ADO is encrypting the password. Does anyone know how it is being encrypted?